# rivets.js is not working with handlebars template

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, rivets.js

I am using rivets.js for data binding in my backbone file. But i am using handlebar templates. so when i display my data in handlebars through rivets, it does not work. It works fine without handlebars.

in my javascript file:

`var obj = {name: 'my name'};
 rivets.bind($('#div1'), {'opp': obj});`

in my handlebar file:

```
{{opp.name}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rivets and handlebars is not supposed to be used together. Rivets supports expressions in the form `{}` (by default) just like handlebars `{{}}`.

Rivets is expecting a "Rivets template", not handlebars template. And handlebars is expecting a handlebars template, not rivets template.

Either use rivets or use handlebars.

Comment: so is there any way view binding in handle bars?

Comment: I have found a link with working example on jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/3j6yLL02/

Comment: @Zeeshan That JSFiddle is not working. BTW `{{expression}}` bindings is not necessarily handlebars. Rivets support it too. I can't think of a reason to use handlebars when you have rivets. Rivets is handlebars and more.